# Convergence in distribution and the limitation of CDF

Tags: probability, limits, continuity

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ that converge to a normal distribution:

$$X_n \to N(\mu,1)$$

In other word, denote the cumulative density function (CDF) of $X_n$ as $F_n(x)$, we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n = \Phi(x-\mu)$$

where $\Phi(x-\mu)$ is the CDF of $N(\mu,1)$.

Intuitively, when $\mu \to 0$, we should have something like:

$$\lim_{\mu \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x) = \Phi(x)$$

Is this true? What's the name of the theorem that supports this claim?

Comment: What does $\lim_{\mu \to 0} X_n$ mean?

Comment: @TychusFindlay sorry, it is a typo. I have edited the question.

Comment: Obviously that is true, since $\Phi(x-\mu)$ is a continuous function in $\mu$. Do you mean $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\rightarrow 0$ implies $X_n$ converge in distribution to $N(0,1)$. assuming the limit distribution is normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. We just need to use the continuity of the CDF of the normal distribution. We have that
$$
\lim_{\mu\to0}\Phi(x-\mu)\to\Phi(x)
$$
as $n\to\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. This holds for any continuous function, not necessarily for a CDF.

I hope this helps.